# Handle multiple animations and views in an Activity

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, view, android-animation

I am facing basic issues in my current Android Application having too many animations on too many views in only one activity. The problem here is no animation is working smoothly when I run my app. Some animations in screen are continuous and some of them are just for one time. But none of this animation working as smoothly as it should to achieve a great User Interface. All the animations are being performed one by one. I am shifted to this application recently so I can't post any images here. Moreover, there are more than 80 views in layout file and more than half views are being visible by animation and some views are meant to be continuously animated through out the application lifecycle. My application is a kind of game totally build on android native code.

**Here are some points I should mention:**

1. There are more than 80 views in single layout file and all those views are initialize into java file at once.
2. Also, there are more than 400 images in drawable folder which is around 41MB.
3. Raw folders also contain sound files around 50MB. These sounds are playing continuously in background and some are playing at specific event like button click.
4. Debug APK size is around 82MB.
5. Some animations are also created runtime so there is no animation file for such animation.

**I have also some doubts which are:**

1. Should I move some views into seperate fragments so single screen can have limited number of views.
2. If I shift views in to separate fragment then there will be difficulties to perform animation on views one by one.
3. Is there any workaround to load such many views and perform animation on them regardless of main UI thread? Because all these animations and views are being performed and loaded into UI thread, my application not working smoothly. And as animations are performing on views so we need to access main UI thread from any other thread.
4. Also there are many apps available on market which has flowless User Interface with so many views and animations on them. So how they manage their app performance. Is there any library or SDK available in market to improve performance for such an application.

In short, I want to know how such applications with such resources, background music and animations should be handled? I just want to handle this application efficiently to improve app performance.

Please guide me where I am doing wrong and some implementation methods I am not aware about. If possible I will post video for my app to get better idea.

Thank you for going through my post!

Answer (score 0):

> there are more than 80 views ... some views are meant to be continuously animated through out the application lifecycle

This is a problem. Android Views are not intended to be used this way. There are entire [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html) dedicated to reducing and optimizing your number of Views, since they are very expensive to render and orchestrate.

The key point that you might be missing is that games in Android are *not* written using `View`s animated inside an Activity. Games are generally written using [OpenGL ES](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html) 2.0, or using a high-level game engine like [Unity](https://unity3d.com/), which uses OpenGL when compiled.

OpenGL is a whole different territory to learn and master, but if you want to develop games, you will need to take the plunge into it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable response! I already gone through OpenGL ES document, but as I have not much experience in OpenGL ES, I didn't find any tutorial to use pre-defined set of images in OpenGL ES. What I found is to just create your own shapes and play with it. I am still searching for more tutorials in OpenGL ES which suits this requirement. Please let me know if there are any tutorials out which meet the requirement for my app. Thanks!